# enum associated values in c

Tags: c, enums

I have an enum declaration as:

```
enum qty { cars = 10, bikes = 9, horses = 9 ... } // total 28
```

How could I add up all the associated values of enumerator-list?

Comment: I don't think you really understand what enums are supposed to be for. It looks like you're trying to (mis)use them as a substitute for an associative array or a struct.

Comment: Also, executable code does not retain the names of the `enums`.  If you want to convert between the `enum` value and the name, you will have to use a table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't know at runtime the contents of an `enum` in C.

Besides, this sounds like a misuse of enumerations. You should use them to define *constants* that you will use inside your code, not to store quantities or stuff like that which should otherwise be *variable*: enumeration values are immutable. Use integer arrays for that purpose; you can loop through these.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to express "for all enums in qty" in C.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to loop thru them in C (you could in Ada ;-) so this is all you can do:

```
int sum = cars + bikes + horses + ...;
```

but like zneak and Tyler said, you're probably not using the right construct.

Answer (score 1):

In C, enums are just mapped to integers. They're not even typesafe, as you can freely substitute members of one enum in places intended for other enums.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an awful lot of these to keep in sync then some preprocessor abuse might come in handy:

```
#define SUM(name, count) + (count)
#define DEF(name, count) name = (count),

enum qty
{
#   define QTY(f) \
    f(cars,  10)  \
    f(bikes,  9)  \
    f(horses, 9)

    QTY(DEF)

    total = 0 + QTY(SUM)
};
```